# Trigger to check logic date update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Building an employee database and we want to make sure the database can't be updated incorrectly with employment end date being before the start date. We want to use a trigger to block the update, throw an error, and rollback.

I know this is wrong but this is where I am:

```
CREATE TRIGGER EmpLeaveWarn on Employee FOR UPDATE 
AS
    IF(select End_Date < Start_Date)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('The End date must come after the Start date')
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN
    END
GO
```

For Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a trigger, just use a constraint:

```
alter table EmpLeaveWarn
    add constraint check_end_date check (End_Date >= Start_Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to acheive this would be by using a check constraint, not a trigger:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT Employee_Date_Check CHECK ( End_Date >= Start_Date)
```